# How to display decimal data type without comma

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, formatting, decimal

I have this model:

```
[Display(Name = "Unit Price")]
public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
```

**HTML**:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UnitPrice, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

When I submit the form, it says that model is invalid and the field must be a number:

> The field Unit Price must be a number.

My question is: How I can format decimal so it will be shown with point?

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ Point... Well It should be visible like a point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a very simple solution

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UnitPrice, String.Format("{0}", Model.UnitPrice.ToString().Replace(",",".")), new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Pick an appropriate [Decimal.ToString() format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also, the way that the number gets rendered on the page may be out of your control - different cultures will render different ways.

Comment: Well... It shows in filed with comma automatically. But when I submit it must be with a point. I dont know how to fix it...